# re-ordering the files in shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sh

In my system file are in below format

```
image0.jpg
image1.jpg
image2.jpg
image3.jpg
  .
  .

  .
  .
  .
image10.jpg
image11.jpg
```

i can order the file using this below script

```
for i in *.jpg; do
    new=$(printf "xome%04d.jpg" "$a") #04 pad to length of 4
        mv -- "$i" "$new"
        let a=a+1
done
```

but what happen is it get the file in this order like `image0.jpg,image10.jpg,image1.jpg,image11.jpg,image2.jpg..............`

how to get sequence using shell script

Comment: if the files are already named `imageN.jpg`, why not take the number from the filename and just pad it out with 0's, instead of using a counter?

Comment: @Mark suggests something like `mv -- "$i" "xome${i%image}"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for i in {1..11}; do
    printf -v newfile "xome%04d.jpg" "$i"
    [ -f "image${i}" ] && mv "image${i}.jpg" "$newfile"
done
```

The `-v` option stores the `printf` result in variable `newfile`.

`[ -f "image${i}" ]` test if file exist before trying to rename.

Comment: You should quote `"$newfile"`.

Comment: @tripleee Maybe as a good practice but in this case, the `$newfile` is made of non-space string.

Comment: In this particular case, yes, but adding two characters to cover the more general problem seems like a modest price to pay.

Comment: You may omit quotes for expansions that are *guaranteed* to be space and glob-free, such as `$#`, but for general variables, it's better to use them even if not strictly necessary than to fail to use them when it is.